# What's the probability of rolling 1 on a die, 3 times in a row?

Tags: probability

Given a D3 die (a die with 3 faces ("1","2","3")), what is the probability of throwing "1" three times in a row? One die, three times.

For one throw it's one possibility of three possibilities, 1/3 = 33%

So the goal is throwing "1", "1" and "1".

Is it 3.6% ( 33% * 33% * 33% ) or is it 33%? Since if you are successful of throwing "1" once, you "start a new" and therefore it's always 33%?

Comment: The confusing thing here is the difference between "vanilla" probability and conditional probability. So if you have $X = \text{throw a 1}$, then
$$
P(X) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
And then the "vanilla" probability $$P(\text{three 1's in a row}) = P(X)\cdot P(X) \cdot P(X)$$. But, if you have already thrown the die two times and gotten 1's, then the **conditional probability**
$$
P(\text{three 1's in a row}~|~\text{you already have thrown two 1's}) = P(X) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
because "in the future" you only need to throw only one 1.

Comment: Per Matti P's comment, answer to original question is $(1/3)^3.$

Comment: As a nitpick... the probability is not $33\%$... it is $33.333333333\dots \%$ or $33.\overline{3}\%$ or $\frac{1}{3}$.  Use equals signs only for exact equality, not for approximations.  Use $\approx$ for approximations.  Whenever possible use exact values unless explicitly instructed otherwise.  That might mean writing things with fractions instead of with decimals which is totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of throwing a 1 *at each roll* is 1/3. So, even if the first two rolls were 1, the probability of the next role being 1 is still 1/3 - the fact that you already threw that twice makes no difference. (See [the gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) for more on that).

That being said, the probability of *all* of the rolls being 1/3 *does* change because there are a lot more possible outcomes to choose from. In fact, as previously indicated, $(\frac{1}{3})^3$ is correct here. Think about it this way: for the first roll, there are 3 possible results (1, 2, or 3). For two rolls, there are nine possibilities because for each possible first roll, there are 3 possible first rolls and three possible second rolls, so there are 9 possible results: (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3). For three dice, there are 27 possible solutions: e.g. (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), etc. The probability of rolling 3 consecutive 3s is therefore $\frac{1}{27} = \frac{1}{3}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

It's (1/3)³ . We can also solve it in this way:

**n(S)**= Sample space = ***3³***, which gives the number of all possible outcomes .

**n(P)**=Number of allowable cases=***1***
Because there's only one case in which 1 comes 3 times in a row .

Therefore , *P(E)=n(P)/n(S)*
=(1/3)³